# How do I find the derivative of a definite integral in which the variable of differentiation is a limit in the integral?

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

The derivative I would like to find is

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} \int_{-z_0}^z (z - z^{\prime}) \; f(z^{\prime}) \; dz^{\prime}$$

where $f(z^{\prime})$ is some arbitrary function of $z^{\prime}$.  So $z$ actually appears twice: once in the upper limit of integration, and once in the integrand.

Comment: Note that the *variable* in the integral is $z'$. The letter $z$ is to be treated as constant until after the integral is done, and you try to differentiate with respect to $z$. BUT: Look at the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus, which deals with this situation directly.

Comment: The subject is well covered in [this Wikipedia entry.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar questions are [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58321/752) and [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/58594/752).

The integral depends on the variable $z$ only, because $z'$ is a dummy variable. So you want to find the derivative of the integral and not its partial derivative. This is a special case of the following more general rule ([Leibniz rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)):

*If* 
    $$I(z)=J(u(z),v(z),z)=\int_{u(z)}^{v(z)} f(z,z')dz',\tag{1}$$

*i.e.* $$\  J(a,b,z)=\int_{a}^{b} f(z,z')dz',\qquad \text{  with   }a=u(z),b=v(z),$$

*then, under suitable conditions, we have*

$$I^{\prime }(z)=\displaystyle\int_{u(z)}^{v(z)}\dfrac{\partial f(z,z')}{\partial z}dz'+f(z,v(z))v^{\prime }(z)-f(z,u(z))u^{\prime }(z).\tag{2}$$

It is a consequence of

$$\frac{dI}{dz}=\frac{\partial J}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial J}{\partial u}
\frac{du}{dz}+\frac{\partial J}{\partial v}\frac{dv}{dz}.$$

The first term is the differentiation under the integral sign

$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial z}=\int_{u(z)}^{v(z)}\dfrac{\partial f(z,z')}{\partial z}dz'$$
 and the other two are a consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$\frac{\partial J}{\partial v}
=f(z,v(z)),\qquad\frac{\partial J}{\partial u}
=-f(z,u(z)).$$

In your case you want do find $$\frac{d }{d z}\int_{-z_{0}}^{z}g(z,z')dz',$$ where $$g(z,z^{\prime })=(z-z^{\prime
})f(z^{\prime }).$$ Since the lower limit of integration is constant, we have two terms only

$$\frac{d }{d z}\int_{-z_{0}}^{z}g(z,z^{\prime
})dz'=\int_{-z_{0}}^{z}\frac{\partial g(z,z^{\prime })}{\partial z}dz^{\prime
}+g(z,z)=\int_{-z_{0}}^{z}f(z')dz^{\prime
},$$

because $g(z,z)=0$ and $\frac{\partial g(z,z^{\prime })}{\partial z}=f(z').$

Answer (score 1):

Introduce a second variable $y$ and set $g(x,y) = \int_{z_o}^{x}(y-z')f(z')dz'$. Calculate $dg$,
$$ dg = \frac{\partial g}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial g}{\partial y}dy $$
Then set $x=y=z$ and find $dg/dz$.