# What is the derivative of $\Big(\int_{0}^t f(i,t)\ di\Big)$ wrt to t?

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Is it even do-able to take the following derivative $$\frac{d\Big(\int_{0}^t f(i,t)\ di\Big)}{dt}$$

if yes, how?

Comment: what does the $\sum_i^t$ notation stand for?

Comment: summation from $i=0$ to $i=t$

Comment: then $t\in\Bbb N$ and how do you take derivative w.r.t. a discrete variable?

Comment: you are right. I was imprecise in defining the notation.

Comment: @user3639557 well, if defined correctly, you can differentiate with respect to a "sum".  Set it equal to a differentiable function equal to the sum for all $t\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: In what you've written, $t$ is a dummy variable of integration; it's meaningless to differentiate with respect to it. Are you asking how to compute something like $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}  \int f(t, s)\, ds$?

Comment: It's still meaningles. Do you mean $\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t} f(s,t)\,ds$? There is no reason for partial derivatives in this case.

Comment: When you differentiate with respect to the integral, you problem want to use the FTOC for it to make sense.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews yes - was just fixing the notation. So this derivative is equal to $\int^{t}_{0}f(i,t)di$? Note that $t$ explicitly appears in $f(i,t)$

Comment: This 2017 post now answers your question: [How to compute $\frac{d}{dt} \int_{a(t)}^{b(t)} f(x,t) dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2084591/how-to-compute-fracddt-int-atbt-fx-t-dx). It was itself a duplicate of [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58594) and [that one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58321), both of 2011 (and probably many others).

Answer (score 2):

Let $g(t)=\int_{0}^{t} f(s,t)\,ds$.

Then $$g(t+h)-g(t)= \int_{0}^{t} (f(s,t+h)-f(s,t))\,ds + \int_{t}^{t+h} f(s,t+h)\,ds$$

So $$\frac{g(t+h)-g(t)}{h} = \int_{0}^{t} \frac{f(s,t+h)-f(s,t)}{h}\,ds + \frac{1}{h}\int_{t}^{t+h} f(s,t+h)\,ds$$

If $f$ is "nice", then the limit of this as $h\to 0$ is:

$$\frac{dg}{dt} = \int_0^t \frac{\partial f}{\partial t}(s,t)\,ds + f(t,t)$$

I forget the conditions under which you can switch the limit and integral, but it is true for lots of $f$.

---

The second term $f(t,t)$ really requires $f$ to be continuous, at least on $t.$

Comment: In general we have $dg(t,y)/dt=(\partial g/\partial t)+(\partial g/\partial y)(dy/dt).$ In this case  let $g(t,y)=\int_0^yf(t,i)di.$